# Unexpected error 'list index out of range'

Tags: python

```
"""
calcGPA
@author: nick young
"""
# GPA Calculator.  Weights letter grade and credit hours and divides to return final GPA value

def calcGPA():
    error=('Improper Input, asshole. GPA is -1.')   #Snarky error message
    i=0 #tally numbers to count from
    a=0
    x=0
    y=0
    list1=list(input("Enter your letter grades earned on an A-F scale:"))
    list2=list(input('Enter the credit hours earned for each course in the same order as your first input \nNo spaces:'))
    list3=[] #empty list to append weighted values to

    if len(list1)!=len(list2) or len(list1)+len(list2)<=0:        #verifies lists are same length and not empty
        print(error)
    elif list1[i].upper() not in ['A','B','C','D','F']:        
        print(error)
        i=i+1
    elif list2[a].isdigit()==False:                              
        a=a+1
        print(error)

    for letter in list1:         #loop determines letter grade and returns numeric value per element in list1
        if letter.upper=='A':    #runs through until each element in list1 has been converted into a numeric value to be weighted
            list3.append(4*list2[x])
            x=x+1
        elif letter.upper=='B':
            list3.append(3*list2[x])
            x=x+1
        elif letter.upper=='C':
            list3.append(2*list2[x])
            x=x+1    
        elif letter.upper=='D':
            list3.append(1*list2[x])
            x=x+1
        elif letter.upper=='F':
            list3.append(0)
            x=x+1

        y=0
    while y<=len(list1):    #loop gathers the collective weight of each class to be divided

        weight=float(0)      
        weight=float(list3[y]*list2[y])
        y=y+1

    gpa=float(weight/sum(list2))    
    print(gpa)    

calcGPA()
```

For this GPA calculator, I need to move through and multiply matching elements in two lists (list2[0]*list3[0]...) for the length of whatever the input is.  The code already checks to verify everything has the same length.  When it is run, the error 'list index out of range' shows up.

After some googling, I hear that this for is when a variable extends beyond the range it should, but from what I see 'y' should not go beyond the length of list1 (which would also be the length of list two and three).  I've tried using only a '<' on the while statement as well.

Side note: I know already this program probably isn't formatted perfectly, but I'm only in week 7 of my class.

Other side note: I'm using Spyder 3 IDE for my compiler

Comment: Look again at the stack trace. It tells you which line of code causes the error.

Comment: Forgot to include that in my post! It specifically did it for

     weight=float(list3[y]*list2[y])

Comment: As a side note, `list1[i].upper() not in ...` checks only if the _first_ grade is invalid, and `list2[a].isdigit()==False` checks only the first number, too. Probably not what you wanted.

Comment: Should I use while loops instead of an if loop to tally up the variables?

Comment: `if` is not a loop. It has a totally different purpose. The rest of your program is a zoo of major errors. I suggest that you slowly go over introductory tutorials, before you fully understand the purpose of basic control structures.

Comment: We've been kind of rushing through the class and I apologize for my general  inexperience.  Just trying to fix this one small problem for a homework problem that I was most definitely not fully ready for.

Answer (score 1):

The initial problem is that you've used the **upper** *property* instead of the **upper** *method*. You need this:

```
for letter in list1:
    if letter.upper()=='A':
        list3.append(4*list2[x])
```

You'll then hit the problem that list2 is a list of characters, not integers.  Try this:

```
        list3.append(4*int(list2[x]))
```

Those should get you over the next couple of humps.

Comment: Fixed a decent number of problems! However, still turned back the same 'IndexError: list index out of range' message for the line 'weight=float(list3[y]*list2[y])'

Comment: I suspect that the problem is that you still have **y<=len(list2)** as your loop control.  You need **y < len(list2)**; better yet, convert this to a **for** loop.

Comment: Yes, you have multiple problems in this code.  What is the value of y at this point?  How many times did you make it through the loop before it died?  What values does it operate on: did you properly convert all the digits (strings) to integers?

If you have a separate problem, we need you to post a new question.  If you have the same problem, we need you to update this question to reflect the current state of your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
while y<len(list1):
```

instead of

```
while y<=len(list1):
```

Indexes are zero-based in most languages so this is what you usually want to do.

Comment: The code I posted did include the '='.  While I was troubleshooting I did test without one as well just to be sure that wasn't the issue.